# Como medir Intensidad en una bomba de agua con NODEMCU

Tags: arduino, esp8266

estoy en la realización de un proyecto de automatización, el hecho es que necesito saber la corriente consumida por una bomba de agua.
El proyecto lo estoy basando en la placa de desarrollo NODEMCU, como se puede observar en la figura.

[image: NODEMCU]

Para poder realizar las lecturas de corriente estoy haciendo uso del sensor SCT 013, como se puede apreciar en la siguiente imagen.

[image: sensor de corriente]

El sensor lo conecte según este esquemático

[image: Esquemático de conexionamiento]

EL código del proyecto es el siguiente.

```
// Include Emon Library
#include "EmonLib.h"
 
// Crear una instancia EnergyMonitor
EnergyMonitor energyMonitor;
 
// Voltaje de nuestra red eléctrica
float voltajeRed = 220.0;
 
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
 
  // Iniciamos la clase indicando
  // Número de pin: donde tenemos conectado el SCT-013
  // Valor de calibración: valor obtenido de la calibración teórica
  energyMonitor.current(0, 2.26);
}
 
void loop()
{
  // Obtenemos el valor de la corriente eficaz
  // Pasamos el número de muestras que queremos tomar
  double Irms = energyMonitor.calcIrms(1484);
 
  // Calculamos la potencia aparente
  double potencia =  Irms * voltajeRed;
 
  // Mostramos la información por el monitor serie
  Serial.print("Potencia = ");
  Serial.print(potencia);
  Serial.print("    Irms = ");
  Serial.println(Irms);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Al momento de probar en la bomba de agua el valor de la corriente no varia como se observa en la siguiente imagen.

[image: Respuesta del circuito]

Estuve investigando y tengo entendido que es mas complicado hacer las lecturas a elementos inductivos o capacitivos, en este caso la bomba de agua, me pase días en foros buscando información pero no logro dar con la respuesta para que funcione correctamente este circuito, espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de bomba de agua? ¿12v, 220v? ¿Bomba de acuario o de estanque? ¿Wattage?

Comment: También puedes chequear midiendo una carga pesada (horno/calentador eléctrico), o usar un voltimetro en el pin A0 para verificar el voltaje de entrada. Además, el ESP8266 funciona a 3.3v, y el código que tienes es para Arduino, que funciona con 5v. Por último, puedes hacer un script que lea e imprima directamente A0, si usar librerias.

Comment: ¿Es 50A/1V? Porque ese ya incluye la resistencia de carga.

Comment: Es una bomba de 220VAC que se suele usar para suministrar agua a en casas, la potencia de la bomba es de 186.425 Watts (1/4 H.P.), entiendo que el rango de operaciones del NODEMCU es de 3.3VDC pero no veo problema con el codigo, podrías ser mas especifico por favor, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: El problema es el circuito, los inductores tienen 0 impedancia con frequencias bajas. entonces si la corriente es constante has de cuenta que el inductor desapareció y fue remplazado por un cable.
**Y la otra cosa es que no puedes medir corriente en paralelo** (hablo de lo mismo en ambos casos en realidad)

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa. El sensor mide la corriente y la expresa en un voltaje 0-1v.

Comment: "Para poder realizar las **lecturas de corriente** estoy...". El gráfico del circuito estrictamente hablando (no es necesario) debería tener una fuente de voltaje en vez de un inductor. A menos que la resistencia que pone sea interna y sea una fuente de equivalencia.
Da para malinterpretar.

Comment: Lo mejor que uno puede hacer para ir descartando es probar con un potenciometro mapeado de 0 a 1v, si funciona el problema está en la adquisición (mal circuito o sensor dañado o mal instrumentado), si no funciona lo que estaría mal es del lado del ESP8266.
Seguir descartando apartir de ahí.

Comment: También probar el sensor por separado con un multimetro, que esté dando valores mayores a 0v y menores a 1v.

Answer (score 1):

Reproduje el circuito. No tengo un sensor de corriente, por lo que use una batería vieja para proveer una señal de ~1.4v.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cable rojo al "+" de la batería, cable verde al "-" de la batería.

Reduje el script a lo esencial:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
     
}
 
void loop()
{
  int value = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(value);
  delay(1000);
}
```

y obtuve valores de 535 en A0 sin señal (0v en la entrada) y 1010 con la batería conectada (~1.4v).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes desconectar el sensor y utilizar una batería para probar tu circuito. Si eso funciona, el problema está con el sensor y/o el cable que debe pasar por su centro.

Comment: Comentarte hice la prueba con una carga resistiva (Un bombillo normal) el codigo y el hardware funcionan bien, el problema nace cuando las cargas son inductivas o capacitivas, en este caso la bomba de agua.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo una bomba de 1/4HP es de 184watt, a 220v la corriente sería máximo 0.84A. y revisando en el datasheet del sensor: [SCT-013-050](https://www.mcielectronics.cl/website_MCI/static/documents/Datasheet_SCT013.pdf) y viendo en la imagen 50/1v, la medición de 0.84A de la bomba darían un rango de 0v a **0.014v** en el sensor.

Asumiendo que en el circuito que muestras el inductor y la resistencia en paralelo son la fuente equivalente de voltaje, y está sobre un divisor de voltaje  3.3v/2=1.65v

El rango que recibiría la entrada analógica A0 sería de 1.65v a 1.79v. No se como sea la conversión en la librería 'energyMonitor' pero viendo la salida, la 'corriente' que está leyendo es de 0.0003636A (220*I=0.08), segun la librería está leyendo **0.016v**/50v=>0.0003636A (mapeando 50A/1v) son los 0.14v que he mencionado antes (suponiendo que la librería resta interamente los 1.65 del divisor de voltaje).

Con resolución del nodemcu de 10bits, es 0-5v por 0-1023 (int), el porcentaje de operacion del sensor ((1.79-1.65)/5)*1024= 28.67 es muy bajo, casi indetectable.

La solución es mejorar el circuito o **cambiar el sensor por uno cuya area de trabajo se acerque más a la del motor**. El sensor es de 0-50A (por lo que veo en la imagen) la bomba llega máximo a 0.84A **estas perdiendo casi el 98.32% del area de trabajo del sensor**

Lo máximo que podrías hacer acondicionando mejor el circuito es con la resolución resultante de 28.67 es medir solo 28 valores de 0 a 0.84A osea 0.03A de resolución resultante.